# segmentation fault (core dumped) when dealing with linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

Ok my program randomly draws cards out of a deck and stores them in an array of linked lists. one list for each suit and the list holds the rank.

```
struct node{
            node(int value = 0) {data=value; next = NULL; }
            int data;
            node *next;

        };

class list{
    public:

        list ();
        ~list();

        bool empty() const {return N == 0;}
        bool full() const {return false;}
        int size()  const {return N;}

        void resize(int);
        void clear();

        void insert(int);
        void remove(int);

        void pop_back() { remove(N-1);}
        const int & back();

        int & operator[](int);

        int findNodeRank(int);

        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, list);

    private:
        int N;
        node *head;

        node *findnode(int);
};

list::list() {
    cout << "making list" << endl;
    head = new node;
    cout << "made list" <<endl;
    }
```

My main function has these lines

```
cout << "here 1" << endl;
list deck[4];
cout << "not here 1";
```

I get the following output after i compile and run my code.

```
here 1
making list
made list
making list
made list
making list
made list
making list
made list
not here 1
before loopHere;
insert
after find node rank
before find node
after find node
[1]    11472 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./Prog2b
```

As you can see it never gets out of making the list array because not here is never called. I dont understand whats going wrong.

OK ive narrowed it down to this function. Ill try to post all relevant code

```
    if (i == 0){                        
        node *p = new node(rankIndex);
        cout << "before find node" << endl;
        node *pp = findnode(N);
        cout << "after find node" << endl;
        p->next = pp->next;
        pp->next = p;

        N++;
    }else {
        prev->next = match->next;       
        match->next = head->next;      .
        head->next = match;            

}
}

int list::findNodeRank(int rankIndex){ //Function similar to findnode that checks for rank match. Returns the index of the match.

    if (head->next == 0)
        return 0;

    node *p = head->next;
    int i = 1;
    cout << "find node rank function" << endl;
    while(p->data != 0){
        if (p->data == rankIndex)
            return i;

        p = p->next;
        i++;
    }

    return 0;                           //Returns 0 if there is no match
}

inline
node *list::findnode(int i) {
    if (i == -1)
        return head;

    node *p = head->next;
    while(i--)
        p = p->next;

    return p;
}
```

Im probably referencing a node that hasn't been created yet or something. Im bad with these linked lists. Ok basically the program like i said draws random cards and stores the results in these lists ive created. The insert function is supposed to add the card to the end of the list if its never been drawn. If the cards been drawn its supposed to move it to the front of the list. Any ideas??

Comment: You don't output `std::endl` after outputting `"not here 1"`, so it's not safe to assume the segfault is caused by creating the list. Something else could be causing it before the next time `std::cout` is flushed. Running it through a debugger will tell you immediately what's causing the segfault.

Comment: It appears all four lists are made. What happens if you put `<< endl` after the "not here 1"?

Comment: Your code looks correct, and it is even working on my machine running Fedora 19 with GCC 4.8.1 20130603.

Comment: Where is the rest of the program? The main fuction?

Comment: Ok I didn't know endl needed to be in there. Ive further narrowed it down any ideas? I edited my original post.

Comment: Instead of guessing where the crash occurred, why not look at the core file and find out?

Comment: Can you run gdb and put up the details? Do something like "gdb program [core]"